# Esper query for when multiple different events occur in one location

Tags: esper

Assuming the following data set, of locations and sensors that have activated (and ignoring time windows at this point for simplicity):

```
Location1       Sensor1
Location1       Sensor1

Location1       Sensor2

Location2       Sensor1
Location2       Sensor1
```

I want to create an Esper query that returns the fact that Location1 has had multiple sensors activated (Sensor1 * Sensor 2).

Whilst Location2 has had multiple activations they were all from the same sensor (Sensor1) so this should not trigger.

In a nutshell I want to say "Tell me when more than one sensor activates at a location".

In pure SQL terms I can achieve this through the following query:

```
SELECT location from
(SELECT DISTINCT location, sensor FROM sensorlog) a
GROUP BY location
HAVING count(location) > 1
```

I'm not able to transpose this directly into Esper though as it seems not to like the subquery.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this in Esper?

My initial attempt was as follows, but this seems to trigger even if a single sensor activates at a single location:

```
select location from SensorEntityWithAsset#time(30 sec) 
group by location, sensor 
having count(sensor) > 1 output every 30 seconds
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Esper and relational databases is that Esper outputs the result as soon as the third row "Location1 Sensor2" shows up. It doesn't allow subqueries in the from-clause as the from-clauses are streams. The subquery can instead be put into the where-clause like so (remove % notebook tags)

```
%esperepl
create schema Event(location string, sensor string);

select * from Event as incoming 
where exists (
  select * from Event#firstunique(location) as existingEvents 
  where existingEvents.sensor != incoming.sensor
)
```

Events ...

```
%esperscenario
Event={location='1', sensor='A'}
Event={location='1', sensor='A'}
Event={location='1', sensor='B'}
```

In case the idea is to also expire events use `Event#firstunique(location)#time(1 hour)` instead.